# restrict page access in php

Tags: php, session

I am trying to restrict page access with role please have a look at my code.

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['user']; echo"<br/>";
echo $_SESSION['roles'];
  if($_SESSION['user']==true ){
    if($_SESSION['roles']=='1'){
      echo "Welcome User";
      }else{ echo "You don't have acces to this page";}
  }else{
    header('location:index.php');
  }
?>
```

Every user can enter admin page. I want only particular roles to be switched to Admin page restricting others. I am managing it with if condition here.

Its not working. any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Any user can enter admin page without having admin role

Answer (score 0):

Remember to **destroy** `$_SESSION['roles']=='1'` after admin logged out. This might be because of session value of admin not destroyed and you tried loginin with userid.